# How can i add item in redux with nested data structure like this? I am adding new items to choice array

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, react-redux, immutability

I want to push new items dynamically to choice array which is nested deeply so that then i can render react native TextInput component dynamically using the map function. Can anyone please help me out. Please find the datastructure and reducer design along with other code below.

```
Use case is like this:
UI: 
 Question:     _________
 Choice:       _________    Add more choices
 Right Choice: _________    Dropdown which gets data from choice array

 Next                  Add New Question
```

On pressing add new question, new object from dynamicMCQGenerationDataFormat[0] is added and then using the map function i than render two questions each having question, choice, right choice properties. I hope this is enough for people to understand.

(On clicking add more choices will be rendered using map function. I have to not only push new items in choice array but later i have to even change the content inside them.)

I have a datastructure dynamicMCQGenerationDataFormat:

```
[
  {
    "question": "What",
    "choice": ["choice"],
    "rightChoice": ""
  }
]
```

Reducer:

```
import {
  EXAM_UPDATE,
  REFRESH_EXAM,
  INSERT_NEW_QUESTION,
  INSERT_NEW_CHOICE,
  UPDATE_QUESTION
} from '../actions/types';
import dynamicMCQGenerationDataFormat from '../assets/MCQGenerationFormat/dynamicMCQGeneration.json';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  description: "",
  level: "",
  status: "",
  mcq: dynamicMCQGenerationDataFormat
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EXAM_UPDATE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value }
    case INSERT_NEW_QUESTION:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return { ...state, mcq: [ ...state.mcq, action.payload] }
    case UPDATE_QUESTION:
      return {
        ...state, mcq: state.mcq.map((mcq, i) => i === action.payload.idx ? {...mcq, question: action.payload.value} : mcq)
      }
    case INSERT_NEW_CHOICE:
      return { ...state, mcq: [...state.mcq, choice: [...state.mcq.choice]] }
    case REFRESH_EXAM:
      return { INITIAL_STATE }
    default:
      console.log('Enroll Guard Form Reducer');
      return state;
  }
};
```

ActionCreator:

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import {
  EXAM_UPDATE,
  EXAMS_FETCH_SUCCESS,
  INSERT_NEW_QUESTION,
  UPDATE_QUESTION,
  INSERT_NEW_CHOICE
} from './types';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

export const examUpdate = ({ prop, value }) => {
  return {
    type: EXAM_UPDATE,
    payload: { prop, value }
  };
};

export const insertNewQuestion = (value) => {
  return {
    type: INSERT_NEW_QUESTION,
    payload: value
  };
};

export const insertNewChoice = (value) => {
  return {
    type: INSERT_NEW_CHOICE,
    payload: value
  };
};

export const questionUpdate = ({ idx, value }) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_QUESTION,
    payload: { idx, value }
  };
}
```

Calling the action creator from one of my react native component:

```
pushNewQuestion() {
    this.props.insertNewQuestion(dynamicMCQGenerationDataFormat[0]);
}
```

Here dynamicMCQGenerationDataFormat is again the same:

```
[
  {
    "question": "What",
    "choice": ["choice"],
    "rightChoice": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: paste the code you are using and we will kindly fix your error

Comment: @DmitriiG. I included the details. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I solved it. For those who face the same problem while updating something deeply nested and cannot denormalize data please refer this.

```
case INSERT_NEW_CHOICE:
  return {
    ...state, mcq: state.mcq.map((mcq, i) => i === action.payload.idx ? {...mcq, choice: [ ...mcq.choice, action.payload.value]} : mcq)
  }

case UPDATE_CHOICE:
  return {
    ...state, mcq: state.mcq.map((mcq, i) => i === action.payload.idx ? {...mcq, choice: [ ...mcq.choice.map((choice, i) => i === action.payload.sIdx ? action.payload.value : choice ) ] } : mcq)
  }
```